# Creating a custom prompt with js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a custom version of the prompt() function in js, that can be styled according to client specs.

However, I am not sure how to get a custom function to pause scripts until a 'yes' or 'no' is selected, and therefore how to get that function to eval to either true or false the same way a simple prompt() would.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to research?

Comment: You can't do this. Prompts are not in the DOM, and there's no way to customize them. Use a modal dialogue instead.

Comment: You can use a library like Sweet Alert.

Comment: You cannot pause page running scripts executions on the main thread while using a custom prompt (HTML, CSS, JS)

Comment: I should mention that this is partly an exercise to teach myself the language, so using a third party lib defeats the purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah `prompt()` can't be styled, it is an in-built browser feature and has no way of pausing until clicked.

As others have said, and also what I would do, is make a modal that you can style to your desire. Then, "promisify" it (in that, create a promise and once you select something, resolve the promise), and this will basically wait until 'yes' or 'no' is clicked.

Comment: I think this is what I was looking for. Looking into promises now. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. They're a very useful thing to learn :)

Comment: What do you mean by: *"and has no way of pausing until clicked"*? Pause what exactly? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: prompt() prevents the users from doing anything but answering yes or no, and then returns true or false based on the response. Seems like this exact thing is not possible but a round about way of doing it through promises should suffice.